# Django/Wagtail Media Files not showing up in the admin portal on a fresh install

Tags: django, media, wagtail

I am working on a site in dev that contains a media folder. When I do a fresh setup of the site (empty db) and do all the migrations and steps to get the site up and running I noticed in the admin portal none of the  images and assets in the media folder dont show up even though they exist. I have to re-import an image and then it shows up in the admin portal as expected. I have looked all over and cannot find an answer. To put it simply why isnt the admin portal importing existing files in the media folder on a fresh setup?

```
django==3.2
wagtail==3.0
```

base.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from wagtail.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

from search import views as search_views


urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That is totally normal. Just as you need to import your page data into the database, you also need to import the information about your documents into the database (in addition to having the files). You can write a script to help with these imports. I don't have one for images but here is one I wrote for importing documents from a nested directory in the file system into a nested set of collections: https://gist.github.com/cnk/54031ca6775fa0d29997449a1e2010ec